# send multiple cc email in odoo to specific group

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-13

I want to add cc emails in odoo-13 (want cc been sent to the direct manager of employee and the HR)
I found related settings in odoo interface\settings\technical\templates but I am not sure if I have to add cc emails here or in code.
can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odoo `mail.template` records are responsible for generated mails from Odoo, located in `settings\technical\templates`, where you can define values like subject, body, from address, to address, CC etc. However those values can be dynamic or static based on the values that set on template, if you need dynamic CC (different for two different sale, for example), you will have to set it dynamically but if you need fixed CC mail address, you can just set that static value on CC field (for example `test@example.com`). You don't need to add CC address to python code. An example of dynamic mail address can be `${object.user_id.email_formatted}` where it will be different for different user sending the email.